# How to print something from similar h files using c++

Tags: c++

i have 2 .h files:

first.h

```
namespace first
    {
    void foo() { std::cout << 1 << ","; }
    void bar() { std::cout << 7; }
    }
```

second.h

```
namespace second 
    {
    void foo() { std::cout << 3 << ","; }
    void bar() { std::cout << 9; }
    }
```

and the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"
```

......................

```
void main() {
     foo();
     bar();
    }
```

The goal is that the main prints `3,7` using these h files above.

Does someone have an idea how I could do it? Thanks

Comment: `using second::foo; using first::bar;`

Comment: Do note that `void main()` has never been allowed in standard C++

Comment: Use the scope operator `second::foo()` and `first::bar()`

Answer (score 5):

You can call the functions using the namespace:

```
second::foo();
first::bar();
```

But if you want to use the same functions over and over you can bring them into your scope via

```
using second::foo;
using first::bar;

foo();
bar();
```